# npm install complains about unmet peer deps that are already met

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I just upgraded to the angular 2 final release from rc-6. I've upgraded several times throughout the beta/rc versions without issue.

My deps in my package.json are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "1.2.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.6",
    "chart.js": "2.1.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "highlight.js": "9.5.0",
    "marked": "0.3.5",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.1.1",
    "ng2-charts": "1.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  }
```

This matches what's on the current (as of this writing) [angular 2 setup page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files).

Running npm install will install everything, but I get a pile of errors at the end:

```
219946 error code EPEERINVALID
219947 error peerinvalid The package @angular/common@2.0.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
219947 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@2.0.0 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0
219947 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0
219947 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0
219947 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.0.0 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0
219947 error peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.0.0 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0
219947 error peerinvalid Peer ng2-bootstrap@1.1.1 wants @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.6
219947 error peerinvalid Peer ng2-charts@1.2.0 wants @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.6
219948 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

As you can see in my package.json, I'm on @angular/common@2.0.0, and there is no higher version than that currently available. The current setup does *not* recommend using `^2.0.0`, but I tried it anyways to no avail.

I have also tried both nuking my entire node_modules directory, as well as installing @angular/common before anything else, both without success. Am I stupid, or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing a was able to reproduce this error, when I ran `npm install` with just a `package.json` file. You should have 4 files prior to running npm install in your angular 2 project. In [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) you need to copy out the following files...

-package.json

-tsconfig.json

-typing.json

-systemjs.config.js

Once you have all these file copied into your project run NPM install again. (the files are nested in tabs just above the package.json file in the tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Either something up with npm:

```
    npm install -g npm
    npm cache clean
    npm update -g
    npm install
```

Or maybe because ng2-bootstrap and ng2-charts pre-req older versions of @angular/common something is going wrong there? Try newer versions?:

```
  "ng2-bootstrap": "1.1.5",
  "ng2-charts": "1.3.0",
```